# What is the ball diameter in the FLSUN SR delta arm joints?

Tags: delta, part-identification

I'm trying to get spring-tensioned cup and ball delta arms for a custom build and considering using premade FLSUN SR arms because they're available at very reasonable prices and there do not seem to be any suppliers for these kinds of ball cup ends as a standalone part. But I can't find any details on the diameter of the balls I'd need to use them. From photos of the FLSUN SR effector it looks like they're about 7mm, but that seems like an odd size and might very well be inaccurate due to perspective. 8mm seems to be the size used by other similar parts including the [SeeMeCNC balls](https://www.seemecnc.com/products/cnc-machined-ball-joint-kit) I'd like to use.

Could someone with one of these printers take a real caliper measurement to help me determine if this part will be suitable or what size balls I might need to look for to make it suitable?