# Are delta ball cup ends available as standalone part?

Tags: printer-building, delta, part-identification

I'm in the process of building a custom delta printer, and based on discussions with folks who do this about the pros and cons of different types of joints, and on [this article](https://www.sublimelayers.com/2017/04/delta-arm-joint-musings.html) I'd really like to get spring-tensioned ball cup joints. The article cites a company called Trick Laser as the source for the ball cup ends used in some such arms, apparently including [the ones SeeMeCNC sells](https://www.seemecnc.com/collections/parts-accessories/products/carbon-fiber-arms-340-5mm-set-of-six) as complete parts, but Trick Laser does not seem to still be in business or at least doesn't seem to have a website, and I've been completely unable to locate anyone selling just the ball cup ends. Short of printing my own in nylon or POM (this is scarily doable and I might actually do it) or buying SeeMeCNC's arms with the wrong length and carefully cutting them off and drilling out the epoxy or whatever, is there any way to get these kinds of ends?

Note that the FLSUN SR uses these kinds of joints, and since its arms are almost a perfect match for what I need, I have [another question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/20732/what-is-the-ball-diameter-in-the-flsun-sr-delta-arm-joints) about the possibility of using them. But I'd really like to know where to get the parts, since I'll probably be doing at least one more build that will need different lengths, and I'd like to be able to publish the design and BOM for others to build.

Comment: Can't the type 1 be engineered into the type 4 by adding a lug and a spring?

Comment: @0scar: That's a good question. I think adding a spring to type 1 (not sure what you have in mind for lug) would get the equivalent backlash protection of type 4.

Comment: The lug on the ball cup end is necessary to attach the spring to.

Comment: @0scar: Ahh, I just wasn't clear what lug meant in this context. So yes, the part missing from my self-answer. :-) I was a little worried about making that reliable at first, but my test piece now is holding something like 5kg with no sign it's even near breaking, so I think it'll handle a spring.

Answer (score 3):

Well, they're available now [as a printable part](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:5939582)! Not yet tested on a real printer, but they move smoothly on metal delta joint balls (tested with Hayden's). I'll follow up with more details on how suitable they are once I've built this.

[image: Printed red ball-cup rod end, with machined steel 3/8" ball and mounting interface sitting in the ball cup]

Apparently printed ball cup ends are a thing other people building deltas do, too: